# Fluent Nhibernate - Schema Mapping Question

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

If in my classmap I have

```
SchemaAction.None();
```

and if I also have

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
             {
                 new SchemaExport(cfg)
                 .Create(false, false);
             })
```

Can I ensure that nhib will not touch the db schema in any fashion.
In other words the only write action will be that of entities to the tables?

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to just leave out the ExposeConfiguration call altogether.

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(....)
    .Mappings(....)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```